# Shiny app: how to go one step/entry back (with a back button) after multiple data entry/series of radio radiobutton entry

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, shinyjs

I have written a shiny app that presents different radio buttons to the user. Depending on the input, numbers will be added to a `score/counter` and other radio buttons will pop up (and the previous will be disabled).

I am wondering now, how I could implement a "step back" button that would the user to go back one step (e.g., in the case of a misclick) which means:

1. Hide the most recent radio button
2. Activate the last radio button again
3. Adjust the `score/counter`

I learned [how to add a "reset" button that calls `session$reload()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062422/restart-shiny-session) which deletes everything and the user can start again. However, it would be much better if the user could just go back one step.

I found similar questions ([Create general purpose "go back" button in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38668388/create-general-purpose-go-back-button-in-shiny) and https://www.collinberke.com/blog/posts/2021-09-12-shiny-implementing-a-next-and-back-button/index.html), however, these questions deal with a slightly different setting.

Example:

ui.R

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  # Add an invisible counter to store the total score
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "counter", placeholder = TRUE),
  
  # Add a radio button with two choices
  radioButtons(inputId = "a",
               # label = "a",
               label = "a",
               choices = c("10", "5"),
               selected = ""),
  
  
  # UI elements for the b and c radio buttons
  uiOutput("b"),
  uiOutput("c"),
  uiOutput("d"),
  uiOutput("c1"),
  uiOutput("e"),
  uiOutput("f"),
  
  # Add a back button to allow the user to go back to the previous question
  actionButton(
    inputId = "reset_button",
    label = "Reset",
    width = "50%"
  ),
  textOutput("reset_val")
  
)
```

server.R

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  reset_rv <- reactiveVal(value = 0L)
  
  
  
  # Initialize the counter to 0
  counter <- reactiveValues(value = 0)
  
  # Track the selected options
  selected_options <- reactiveValues(
    a = NULL,
    b = NULL,
    d = NULL,
    c = NULL,
    e = NULL,
    f = NULL
  )
  
  # Update the counter when the a radio button is clicked
  observeEvent(input$a, {
    if (!is.null(input$a)) {
      selected_options$a <- input$a
      if (input$a == "5") {
        counter$value <- counter$value + 0
        output$b <- renderUI({
          radioButtons(inputId = "b",
                       label = "b",
                       choices = c("a", "10"),
                       selected = "")
        })
        
      } else if (input$a == "10") {
        counter$value <- counter$value + 8
        output$c <- renderUI({
          radioButtons(inputId = "c",
                       label = "c",
                       choices = c("L", "R"),
                       selected = "")
        })
    
        
        }}
    shinyjs::disable("a")
    })

  

# 2 -----------------------------------------------------------------------

  observeEvent(input$b, { 
    if (!is.null(input$b)) {
      selected_options$b <- input$b
      if (input$b == "5") {
        counter$value <- counter$value + 0
        output$d <- renderUI({
          radioButtons(inputId = "d",
                       label = "d",
                       choices = c("5", "10"),
                       selected = "")
        })
      } else if (input$b == "10") {
        counter$value <- counter$value + 6
        output$c1 <- renderUI({
          radioButtons(inputId = "c1",
                       label = "c",
                       choices = c("L", "R"),
                       selected = "")})}}
    shinyjs::disable("a")
    shinyjs::disable("b")
    })
  
    
  
  observeEvent(input$c, {
    if (!is.null(input$c)) {
      selected_options$c <- input$c
      if (input$c == "R") {
        counter$value <- counter$value + 0
        output$e <- renderUI({
          radioButtons(inputId = "e",
                       label = "e",
                       choices = c("5", "10"),
                       selected = "")
        })
      } else if (input$c == "L") {
        counter$value <- counter$value + 4
        output$f <- renderUI({
          radioButtons(inputId = "f",
                       label = "L",
                       choices = c("5", "10"),
                       selected = "")})}}
    
    shinyjs::disable("a")
    shinyjs::disable("c")
    })    
  
  
  
  # Update the counter output
  output$counter <- renderText({
    paste("Score:", counter$value)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$reset_button, {
    reset_rv(input$reset_button)
    session$reload()
  })
  

  
}
```

Run

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest (as almost always) to drop `renderUI` and use a updateXXX-function (`updateRadioButtons`) instead, as re-rendering an element is slower than updating an existing element.

Furthermore, you can take advantage of `radioButtons`' `choiceNames`/`choiceValues` construct to avoid lengthy if clauses.

To hide the elements I'm using `conditionalPanels`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "counter_text", placeholder = TRUE),
  radioButtons(inputId = "a",
               label = "a",
               selected = "",
               choiceNames  = c("10", "5"),
               choiceValues = c(8L, 0L)),
  conditionalPanel("input.a == 0", style = "display: none;",
                   radioButtons(inputId = "b",
                                label = "b",
                                selected = "",
                                choiceNames  = c("a", "10"),
                                choiceValues = c(0L, 6L))),
  conditionalPanel("input.a == 8", style = "display: none;",
                   radioButtons(inputId = "c",
                                label = "c",
                                selected = "",
                                choiceNames  = c("L", "R"),
                                choiceValues = c(4L, 0L))),
  conditionalPanel("input.b == 6", style = "display: none;",
                   radioButtons(inputId = "c1",
                                label = "c",
                                selected = "",
                                choiceNames = c("L", "R"),
                                choiceValues = c(0L, 0L))),
  conditionalPanel("input.b == 0", style = "display: none;",
                   radioButtons(inputId = "d",
                                label = "d",
                                selected = "",
                                choiceNames = c("5", "10"),
                                choiceValues = c(0L, 0L))),
  conditionalPanel("input.c == 0", style = "display: none;",
                   radioButtons(inputId = "e",
                                label = "e",
                                selected = "",
                                choiceNames = c("5", "10"),
                                choiceValues = c(0L, 0L))),
  conditionalPanel("input.c == 4", style = "display: none;",
                   radioButtons(inputId = "f",
                                label = "L",
                                selected = "",
                                choiceNames = c("5", "10"),
                                choiceValues = c(0L, 0L))),
  actionButton(
    inputId = "undo_button",
    label = "Undo",
    width = "25%",
    icon = icon("rotate-left")
  ),
  actionButton(
    inputId = "reset_button",
    label = "Reset",
    width = "25%",
    icon = icon("xmark")
  ),
  textOutput("reset_val")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  radioButtonIds <- list("a", "b", "c", "c1", "d", "e", "f")
  counter <- reactive({
    # disable input after a selection was made
    lapply(radioButtonIds, function(inputId){if(isTruthy(input[[inputId]])){disable(inputId)}})
    # sum up all inputs (irrelevant inputs are set to 0)
    sum(unlist(lapply(radioButtonIds, function(inputId){as.integer(input[[inputId]])})))
  })
  observeEvent(input$undo_button, {
    # reset inputs in their hierarchical order the first check (has an entry been made?) is done on the lowest level
    if(isTruthy(input$c1) || isTruthy(input$d) || isTruthy(input$e) || isTruthy(input$f)){
      lapply(list("c1", "d", "e", "f"), function(inputId){
        updateRadioButtons(session, inputId, selected = character(0))
        enable(inputId)
      })
    } else if(isTruthy(input$b) || isTruthy(input$c)){
      lapply(list("b", "c"), function(inputId){
        updateRadioButtons(session, inputId, selected = character(0))
        enable(inputId)
      })
    } else if(isTruthy(input$a)){
      updateRadioButtons(session, inputId = "a", selected = character(0))
      enable("a")
    }
  })
  observeEvent(input$reset_button, {
    # reset all inputs independent of the hierarchy
    lapply(radioButtonIds, function(inputId){
      updateRadioButtons(session, inputId, selected = character(0))
      enable(inputId)
    })
  })
  output$counter_text <- renderText({
    paste("Score:", counter())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

PS: in this context you might want to check library([shinyglide](https://juba.github.io/shinyglide/)).

Comment: Thank you very much for this beautiful approach. The reset button is marvellous. However, in my example, `a10` jumps to `c` and `a5` jumps to `b` (the data entry forks based on user entry and follows unique paths). In your approach, both `a10` and `a5` jump to `b`. I tried to change it but I could not do it. Is it possible to keep the forked paths with your approach?

Comment: @ava I've edited my answer to reproduce the paths provided in your example code.

Comment: Perfect. I understand the `ui` now, `conditionalPanels` Is indeed very convenient. I could not fully follow the logic of the `server` part yet (especially changes needed if I added some more layers/forks by adding `conditional Panel`s in the `ui`), could you maybe add a few comments there? Just for my understanding.  Thank you.

Comment: @ava I added a few comments in the code.

Comment: Thank you. A last question. If  `choiceValues` has the same value for two `choiceNames` (e.g., `choiceValues = c(8L, 8L)`), how can I refer to them in the `conditionalPanel`? Could I also use the `choiceNames`?

Comment: There might be a way to access the `choiceNames` via JS but I'm currently not aware of it. The `choiceValues` in this scenario should be unique for each input. We could introduce a mapping (index the choices) in this case before calculating the sum.